# CMB Admin Checkbox if statement

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a checkbox on a Wordpress admin options page that if checked I want to call a file. After hours of searching I am still coming up short. I am trying to use the advice here: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks#using-cmb2-helper-functions-and-cmb2_init as well as a confitional statement inside. Is there any advice on what I am doing wrong?

```
function cmb2_init_check_field_value() {
                $checkbox_value = cmb2_get_field_value( 'compel_option_metabox', 'compel_checkbox', get_queried_object_id() );
                if($checkbox_value == yes) {
                    require_once( $this->directory_path . '/post-types/staff.php' );
                require_once( $this->directory_path . '/post-types/sermons.php' );
                }
            }
            add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'cmb2_init_check_field_value' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cmb2_admin_init` hook is too early,so you can not use `get_the_ID()` to get the post

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this as well.  I couldn't figure out how to get the field value function to work.  However, I did figure out how to get the value using the get_post_meta function.

eg:

```
$checkbox_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'compel_checkbox', true);
if($checkbox_value == 'on') {
```